# What is using my RAM?

Tags: ram

My laptop has started swapping like a cat: When I do nothing, it does nothing, but as soon as I do something it starts swapping.

```
$ free
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        32691536    27932080      725360     2694016     4034096     1311600
Swap:      165950456    80476784    85473672
```

Based on this I would expect 27-4 GB = 23 GB is used for resident programs. But according to `ps` only 7.5 GB are used by RSS:

```
$ ps aux | perl -ane '$s+=$F[5];END{print "$s\n"}'
7596328
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If Linux, `ps aux --sort -rss | head` will show the processes using the most memory.

Answer (score 0):

zfs.

zfs uses ~8GB kernel RAM.

Not loading `zfs` gave back most of the missing mem back.

Comment: Errr ? AFAIK ZFS is supposed to use 50 % of the host memory for the ARC. But it's just a default value you can tune in zfs.conf. Now my turn to ask : What am I missing ?